# Hibernate Error: "Column 'header_id' cannot be null" when updating entity with OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, jpa, backend

I'm working with a Spring Boot application using Hibernate and I'm facing an issue when trying to update an entity with a OneToMany relationship. The Header entity has a list of Colonne entities, and I'm using a cascading type of CascadeType.ALL with orphanRemoval=true. However, when I try to update a Header and save it using the save method from Spring Data JPA, I get the error Column 'header_id' cannot be null.
`@Entity
@Table(name = "header")
public class Header {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "header_id")
private List<Colonne> colonne = new ArrayList<>();

}

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "colonne")
    public class Colonne {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "header_id", nullable=false)
    private Header header;

}
@Transactional
public Header updateHeader(Integer id, Header headerDetails) {
Header existingHeader = headerRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
if (existingHeader == null) {
    return null;
}
   existingHeader.setNom(headerDetails.getNom());
   existingHeader.setPosition(headerDetails.getPosition());

    Set<Integer> updatedColonneIds = headerDetails.getColonne().stream()
        .map(Colonne::getId)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

List<Colonne> colonnesToRemove = existingHeader.getColonne().stream()
        .filter(col -> !updatedColonneIds.contains(col.getId()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

existingHeader.getColonne().removeAll(colonnesToRemove);
colonnesToRemove.forEach(col -> {
    col.setHeader(null);
    colonneRepository.delete(col);
});

// ... rest of the update logic

return headerRepository.save(existingHeader);
```

}
`
The error occurs when I call headerRepository.save(existingHeader);. The logs show that Hibernate is trying to set header_id to null for some Colonne entities, which is not allowed. I've tried several approaches to solve this, including using entityManager.flush() after removing the Colonne entities, but the problem persists.

Any ideas on what could be causing this issue or how I could further diagnose it?

Ensuring that the @Transactional annotation is used to manage the transaction boundary around the update operation.
Explicitly setting the parent Header on each Colonne instance before saving the Header.
Using orphanRemoval=true on the @OneToMany relationship to automatically handle the removal of orphaned Colonne instances.
Attempting to manually remove the orphaned Colonne instances from the existingHeader and using colonneRepository.delete(col) to ensure they are removed from the database.
I was expecting that Hibernate would handle the update correctly by deleting the orphaned Colonne entities and updating the existing ones without attempting to set the header_id to null since I am managing the relationship on both sides correctly. However, despite these attempts, I still receive a DataIntegrityViolationException with the message that header_id cannot be null when the update method is called.

I am looking for insights into why Hibernate attempts to set header_id to null and how to ensure that the update operation correctly reflects the changes in the Header and Colonne entities without violating the database constraints.